# ¿ Que tipo de gráfico es este?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Tengo un pequeño problema con python y matplotlib.
Tengo un csv con 382 filas y 58 columnas del tipo:

> Date/Time         0.00   0.05  ...   8.25   8.50   8.75   9.00   9.25  9.50   9.75  10.00
>
> 03/05/17 00:05:26 0.018  0.018  ...  0.001  0.001  0.001  0.001  0.001  0.001  0.001  0.001
>
> 03/05/17 00:07:27 0.033  0.036  ...  0.001  0.001  0.001  0.001  0.001  0.001  0.001  0.001
>
> ...

y necesito generar un gráfico como el de abajo, concretamente el que pone L (g/m3)

Las alturas son los 0.00,0.05,...,10.00

Alguien podría darme alguna pista de como hacer ese gráfico o por lo menos que tipo de gráfico es?

Estoy trabajando en python.

Muchísimas gracias de antemano por vuestras sugerencias.

Un saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que es algo como un spectrograma. Entonces debería ser un mapa de calor donde el eje x es el tiempo, el y es el espectro y el color es el valor de cada espectro en cada momento. Tal vez esto te ayude algo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282368/plotting-a-2d-heatmap-with-matplotlib

Comment: Comparto una analogía útil en el que el valor de cada casilla del CSV es realmente el color del pixel que quieres pintar en el mapa de calor, por lo que tu matriz de datos se puede dibujar como una imagen 2D. Luego, metadatos como la fecha y los rangos del espectro pasan a dar información acerca de los ejes, sin embargo la matriz sigue siendo análoga a los valores de los pixeles de una imagen (en escala de grises, o como en tu ejemplo una escala de colores de rojo a azul)